# using a v-dialog in a v-for loop overwrites click event for all but last v-dialog when using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an app that is using a **Vuetify** `v-dialog` in a `v-for` loop. However, although the separate activator components render correctly within each `v-dialog`, when I click on one of the chips it emits the click event for the last `v-chip` regardless of what chip i click on..

It is as though all the `v-dialogs` are using the same click event to submit the data from the last `v-chip`.

Why is the corresponding click event for each `v-dialog` not being invoked when a chip is clicked?

Demo:
https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/ExyQRxB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an object instead of an array and replace `removeTagDialogs[removeTagDialogs.indexOf(tag.id)]` with `removeTagDialogs[tag.id]`, in both places.

See it working: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/WNxMyMa

Comment: personally, I'd use the `index` (or `iii` in OP's code) rather than `tag.id` in `removeTagDialogs[iii]` ... since, `iii` is guaranteed to be unique within this loop, but `tag.id` depends on data

Comment: I noticed. it got reset for some reason. I just re-applied all changes. Should be all good now.

Comment: I've fixed the comment now :p oh, but - any thoughts on the rest of the comment?

Comment: I'm not sure using array and using the item's index would have fixed it. I'll try, to make sure.

Comment: @J, it looks to me like the problem lies with `removeTagDialogs[removeTagDialogs.indexOf(tag.id)]` syntax. Not sure what `v-model` does in a `<v-dialog>` (not much of a Vuetify fan here).

Comment: no, I was suggesting your fix of using an Object, but use `iii` instead - and really, it's nothing to do with vuetify, just vue